# Why we writing loading view last code variable codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

Why do I pass a variable name when calling a view file?

For example: `$this->load->view("{$viewData->viewFolder}/{$viewData->subViewFolder}/index", $viewData);`

Why we writing $viewData at a last code line?

Comment: `$dataView` instead of `$viewData`, it's variable you can name whatever you want. When it means for you.

Comment: Thanks but my up code is:  $viewData = new stdClass();

Comment: try to give more details in you're want.

Answer (score 2):

no need to load variable:

```
$data['view'] = 'folername/view_file_namae';
$this->load->view('you can call common file for header/footer here', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass a variable name to view file,

```
$this->data['anyname'] = $variable;
$this->load->view('viewfilename',$this->data);
```

and In your view file name, access your passed data as `echo $anyname;`.
You can pass a variable or an array as you want.

If you want to **append** a variable name to a view file, you can use redirect() function.

Source : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#redirect

e.g.

```
redirect('home/category/'.$variable, 'refresh');
redirect('home/category/subcategory/'.$variable, 'refresh');
```